# How to wrap graphqlRequestBaseQuery to handle an expiring access token in Redux-toolkit rtk-query graphql application?

Tags: graphql, access-token, rtk-query

Does anyone have a good example that wraps graphqlRequestBaseQuery so that it refreshes the access and refresh tokens when the access token expires? Here is the code I have so far.

I tried wrapping graphqlRequestBaseQuery but I'm unsure what the arguments should be using typescript.

```
import { createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { graphqlRequestBaseQuery } from "@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query";
import { ClientError } from "graphql-request";

import { RootState } from "../store";

const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_TECHNOTES_API_HTTP_GRAPHQL;
const techNotesHttpAPI = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "http://localhost:4001/graphql";

const baseQuery = graphqlRequestBaseQuery<
  Partial<ClientError> & { statusCode: number; error: string }
>({
  url: techNotesHttpAPI,
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const state = getState() as RootState;
    const token = state.auth.token;

    if (token) {
      headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    }

    return headers;
  },
  customErrors: ({ name, stack, response }) => {
    const {
      message = "",
      statusCode = 500,
      error = "",
    } = response?.errors?.length
      ? response?.errors[0]?.extensions.response
      : {};

    return {
      name,
      message,
      statusCode,
      error,
      stack,
    };
  },
});

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["User", "Note"],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it to work but had to revert back to using GraphQLClient (graphql-request version 4.3.0) as I couldn't find a way to set {credentials: "include"} without it.